# Control Position Relative to Container VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to center the control horizontally and add it to the bottom of form vertically. Here is the code I used, but I think I am missing something obvious. It gets centered horizontally but the vertical position of control is too low.

```
picBox.Location = New Point((Me.Width - picBox.Width) / 2, Me.Height - picBox.Height)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the Height on the form is not what you think of as visible height. This includes the top bar and border height too. Same for the width but often less noticeable.

Comment: What type of object is `Me`?  Is it a form?

Comment: Try doing the `/ 2` like you did on the width.

Comment: Thanks Steve I got it now, I used ClientSize.Width and Height, this does not include borders, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Anchor` property - exactly for this purpose.
Remove horizontal anchors - centered horizontally, 
Remove Top anchor and add Bottom anchor for keeping control bounded to the bottom border

Comment: I couldn't use anchor because I also need to move the control later